# Add up the total cost

Tags: c#

I am trying to get TotalCost to add 150 to it then if the area is larger then 750 add 50 to TotalCost again.

```
int TotalCost = 0;
double Area = Convert.ToDouble(SurfAreaTxt.Text);

if (WoodTxt.Text.ToLower() == mahogany)
{
    TotalCost + 150;
    if (Area > 750)
    {
        TotalCost += 50;
    }
    Console.Write(TotalCost);
}
```

Comment: your first `TotalCost` line isn't using `+=`

Comment: You got your answer, but before your next question please read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it, just change `TotalCost + 150;` to `TotalCost += 150;`.

Here you go:

```
TotalCost = 0;
double Area = Convert.ToDouble(SurfAreaTxt.Text);

if (WoodTxt.Text.ToLower() == mahogany)
{
    TotalCost += 150;

    if (Area > 750)
        TotalCost += 50;

    Console.Write(TotalCost);
}
```

Comment: He specified `area is larger then 750` not mentioned anything regarding `>=`

Comment: if i want to down-vote means i will do it along with my first comment, or with the second comment.